# how to find OAuth flow type from controller after authentication?

Tags: authentication, identityserver4, asp.net-apicontroller

I use IdentityServer4 to protect my .Net Core based API. In my API controllers, I need to determine what type of authentication flow (client credential, authorization code, etc.) the client is using. But I can't find it from ClaimsPrincipal or anywhere else. How can I find the flow from API controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For WEB.API's in ASP.NET Core you alawys use the AddJwtBearer method in your startup class to protect it. It will look at the incoming request and then if a valid token is found, create a ClaimsPrincipal user.

Then if you are not seeing any claims in the ClaimsPrincipal, then that can depend on many other factors, what does your access token contain? and what ClaimsMapping have you done.

Like this picture show:
[image]

To tell the clients apart in the API, you can use [ClientClaims](https://docs.duendesoftware.com/identityserver/v5/fundamentals/claims/) in IdentityServer .

Like this picture from one of my training classes shows:

[image]

Comment: thank you for your explanation! I apologize if my question was misleading but I am all fine getting token and getting authenticated (for my MVC client) to access my APIs. What I need is to be able to find the grant type (or OAuth flow type) of my clients from inside API. I need this info for authorization purpose - for authorization code grant type (as in MVC client), I use user ID for authorization; for client credential type, I will use client id instead. That's why I am looking for grant type so my API can tell the clients apart and get the correct identity. How can I get this information?

Comment: Thank you. That makes sense. I thought that information was already in the token somewhere. Now I know I need to add a ClientClaim for it. I will try it.